# Is there a way to Convert a FindIterable<Document> into JSONArray string?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I got something like this

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(db);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(col);

FindIterable<Document> results = collection.find();
```

I can get the JSONArray String using:

```
JSON.serialize(results)
```

but it's deprecated in the latest version of mongodb driver.

And in MongoDB shell I can use:

```
db.$.find().toArray();
```

But i didn't find anything like this in the driver for Java.

I solved using a List and iterating over the cursor.

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = results.iterator();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

while(cursor.hasNext())
    list.add(cursor.next().toJson());

return list.toString();
```

Feel free to suggest a better solution anyway.

Comment: What you are doing (iterating and calling `toJson()` on each `Document`) is the recommended replacement for use of the `JSON` utility class. From [the commit which deprecated that class](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/commit/63409f9cb3bbd0779dd5139355113d9b227dfa05): "Applications should replace its use with JsonReader, JsonReader, and the toJson/parse methods on BasicDBObject that wrap them.".

Answer (score 7):

Use the spliterator() on the find iterable, then stream, map to String and collect:

```
StreamSupport.stream(collection.find().spliterator(), false)
        .map(Document::toJson)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"))
```

Note that parallel streaming will not work on a mongo result, so keep the `parallel` flag to `false`.

Comment: Does the StreamSupport.stream(...).collect(...) preserve the initial collection.find(...) order/sort ?

Comment: @bastienenjalbert Yes

Answer (score 0):

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52198430/3636639) may result in resource leak as the iterator that is created inside of `collection.find().spliterator()` is never closed and it needs to be in order to return the connection to connection pool.
To fix that you would need to do it as follows:

```
try (MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator()) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(cursor,0), false)
                        .map(Document::toJson)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Or without usage of streams:

```
return collection.find()
                 .map(Document::toJson)
                 .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

In that case the resource (MongoCursor) is also properly closed.